# Wait only 5 second for user input

Tags: c

I want to write a simple c program in turbo c++ 4.5 editor such that in only wait 5 seconds for user input. As an example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  int value = 0;
  printf("Enter a non-zero number: ");

  // wait only 5 seconds for user input
  scanf("%d",&value);
  if(value != 0) {
    printf("User input a number");
  } else {
    printf("User dont give input");
  }
}
```

So, what will be the code for 5 seconds wait for 'scanf' functionality and otherwise execute if-else part.

Comment: `man select`.  Use a timeout for `select`.  You will not be able to use `scanf`, but will have to `read`.  This will be a good exercise.

Comment: `turbo c++ 4.5` ? ahh, come on its 2K13

Comment: @P0W; I bet you he is an Engineering student.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a select(2) loop: https://www.mirbsd.org/man2/select on stdin (fd#0) with a timeout of 5 seconds; run the scanf(3) only if select returns indicating there is data. (See the c_read() function in the mksh source code for an example.)

Other functions, like poll(2), are also possible. Nonblocking I/O is a bit overkill.

OK, here’s a working (on MirBSD) example using select:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int value = 0;
    struct timeval tmo;
    fd_set readfds;

    printf("Enter a non-zero number: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    /* wait only 5 seconds for user input */
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(0, &readfds);
    tmo.tv_sec = 5;
    tmo.tv_usec = 0;

    switch (select(1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tmo)) {
    case -1:
        err(1, "select");
        break;
    case 0:
        printf("User dont give input");
        return (1);
    }

    scanf("%d", &value);
    if (value != 0) {
        printf("User input a number");
    } else {
        printf("User dont give input");
    }
    return (0);
}
```

You might want to play with the exit codes a bit and sprinkle a few \n throughout the code. The `fflush(stdout);` is important so that the prompt is shown in the first place…

Comment: Nice solution. Tested on Linux, no async-io overhead occurred. [strace](http://pastebin.com/7REteyji)

Comment: Linux is using inotify under the hood. wouldn't have expected that! :)

Comment: Me neither. [kdump without input](http://sprunge.us/CddD) and [kdump with input](http://sprunge.us/LTQE) on MirBSD (with `-static`).

Comment: I don't know what inotify is, but yes, this means that, other than the select() syscall, there is no overhead for this solution. Feel free to browse the [manual pages](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/) of the various BSDs for this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42810/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-mirabilos)

Comment: Didn't work for me. Maybe this works only for Linux?

Comment: @Scott I’ve written and tested this on a _very_ classical BSD, so it should work somewhat universally (basically, if your OS has socket networking, and for some that don’t). “Didn’t work for me” is not an error description, either…

Comment: My compiler coudn't find ```#include <err.h>```

Comment: Oh, right, that’s a BSD thing. You can drop that and replace `err(NUMBER, STRING, REST);` with `fprintf(stderr, STRING ": %s", REST, strerror(errno)); exit(NUMBER);`

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler(int signo)
{
  return;
}

int main()
{
  int x;
  struct sigaction sa;

  sa.sa_handler = handler;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

  alarm(5);

  if (scanf("%d", &x) == 1)
  {
    printf("%d\n", x);
    alarm(0); // cancel the alarm
  }
  else
  {
    printf("timedout\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That has race conditions… you really must disable the alarm ASAP. (Also, what if it triggers inside of scanf?)

Answer (score 0):

well you can use the `halfdelay()` function from the curses library